# Symbolic link that works but pointed directory does not exist

Tags: bash, terminal

I am very confused because I am trying to locate the cwd of a process and I can open the cwd using the symbolic link but seems like the directory itself does not exist. See image:

[image]

As you can see, the process exists and the current working directory points to /opt/app/fact_radare_viewer, but that folder does not exist in my system. However I can access it using the symbolic link.

EDIT thanks to @AlexisBRENON:

I tried while in /proc/3618/cwd, something like sudo ls -lah $(pwd -P), or at least pwd -P.

[image]

What is this sorcery?

Comment: Are you sure that there isn't any non-printable character (e.g. control characters) in your path. Maybe you can try, while in `/proc/3618/cwd`, something like `sudo ls -lah $(pwd -P)`, or at least `pwd -P` which should return the resolved path of your current workind directory.

Comment: is /opt/app or somewhere in that path mounted via NFS ?

Comment: Can you list the content of `/opt` and of `/opt/app`? Based on the idea of @tomgalpin, can you give use the output of `mount -l`?

Comment: @AlexisBRENON My initial thought was that its NFS mounted with root squash or something, but root has access to the child directory ??